# choosing authentication to google api in batch application

Tags: java, authentication, google-data-api

In reviewing my options for authenticating against the Google Data API (using the Picasa Web Albums), I'm provided the options noted here:
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/GettingStarted.html

However, the application I'm working with is a batch application (bulk upload of photos), and these all seem geared toward applications with user-interactions (i.e. it seems they're restricted to obtaining a user's password via a redirect to a web page).

As well, after multiple uploads the server API prompts for a captcha confirmation, and blocks further upload until that is obtained.

Am I simply running up against imposed restrictions to protect their bandwidth?

**Update**

Here's the code that is doing the insert; a new instance of com.google.gdata.client.photos.PicasawebService is created for each worker thread.  The pool of worker threads is constrained to about 10-20 threads, and each thread is assigned to upload a single image (or create an album):

```
    PicasawebService service = new PicasawebService(Constants.APPLICATION_AGENT);
    try {
        service.setUserCredentials(
            credentials.username(),
            credentials.password()
        );
    } catch (com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException e) {
        throw new AuthenticationException(e);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using PicasawebService.insert? http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/media/MediaService.html#insert(java.net.URL, E)

Comment: Short answer is yes, but updated to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/batch.html#Batch_API

Comment: I've not, but may consider it. Was hoping to do the uploading of images in parallel to speed up large uploads, though. Nevertheless, the issue is around authentication of the service.  Whether I use the batch API or not is not really relevant.